# Cannot access kube-apiserver remotely

Tags: kubernetes

Following is my kubernetes version details:

```
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"5", GitVersion:"v1.5.1", GitCommit:"82450d03cb057bab0950214ef122b67c83fb11df", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2016-12-14T00:57:05Z", GoVersion:"go1.7.4", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"5", GitVersion:"v1.5.1", GitCommit:"82450d03cb057bab0950214ef122b67c83fb11df", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2016-12-14T00:52:01Z", GoVersion:"go1.7.4", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

**kubectl cluster-info** gives the following output

```
Kubernetes master is running at http://localhost:8080
```

**kubectl --server=localhost:8080** get pods works fine:

```
NAME                     READY     STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
nginx-3449338310-sc54z   1/1       Running   0          3d
nginx-3449338310-sfql2   1/1       Running   0          3d
nginx-controller-0hq0n   1/1       Running   0          2h
nginx-controller-sc0nc   1/1       Running   0          2h
```

But this doesn't work when accessing via IP address: **kubectl --server=10.10.65.151:8080**

```
The connection to the server 10.10.65.151:8080 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?
```

This is my kube-config:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Config
clusters:
- name: kubernetes
  cluster:
    certificate-authority: /etc/kubernetes/pki/ca.crt
    server: http://10.10.65.151:8080
users:
- name: kubeuser
  user:
    client-certificate: /etc/kubernetes/pki/kube-master.crt
    client-key: /etc/kubernetes/pki/kube-master.key
contexts:
- context:
    cluster: kubernetes
    user: kubeuser
  name: kubeuser-context
current-context: kubeuser-context
```

I get the same error while trying to access the api-server from a remote machine. May I know what's missing?

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to connect on the cluster IP, which is internal only.

Use the host's IP

Comment: The issue is with the host's IP.

Answer (score 0):

I had to provide the following parameter to kube-apiserver service to enable access to api server using IP address.

```
--insecure-bind-address=0.0.0.0
```

Now I am able to access the api using IP address of the host.